# how to draw a circle with black border with pstricks?

Tags: pstricks, pst-electricfield

I would like to draw a circle with black bounder in that electric field. Can you help me?

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-electricfield}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}(-6,-6)(6,6)
\psframe*[linecolor=white!50](-6,-6)(6,6)
\psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=gray,griddots=10]
\psElectricfield[Q={[-1 -2 2][1 2 2][-1 2 -2][1 -2 -2]},linecolor=red, radius=1.0]
%\psEquipotential[Q={[-1 -2 2][1 2 2][-1 2 -2][1 -2 -2]},linecolor=blue](-6.1,-6.1)(6.1,6.1)
%\psEquipotential[Q={[-1 -2 2][1 2 2][-1 2 -2][1 -2 -2]},linecolor=green,linewidth=2\pslinewidth,Vmax=0,Vmin=0](-6.1,-6.1)(6.1,6.1)
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also need [`pst-electricfield.pro`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-electricfield/pst-electricfield.pro).

HERE'S THE FILES:

http://wikisend.com/download/401052/pst-electricfield.pro

Comment: I can't compile your code, and I'm note sure why. Can you compile it as it is?

Comment: I compiled it with XeLatex. you also need the file .pro

Comment: Ok. Try to format properly your post, so that it can be copy-and-pasted easily. Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help You can edit your own post.

Comment: Where should be the circle? Which characteristics?

Comment: i draw with black every circle.

Comment: @Clément I added the link to download the file *.pro. You have to compile the file .tex but in the same folder you have to have the file pst-electricfield.pro

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-electricfield}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture*}(-6,-6)(6,6)
    \psframe*[linecolor=white!50](-6,-6)(6,6)
    \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=gray,griddots=10]
    \psElectricfield[Q={[-1 -2 2][1 2 2][-1 2 -2][1 -2 -2]},linecolor=red, radius=1.0]
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white,dimen=inner](-2,2){1}
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white,dimen=inner](2,-2){1}
    \end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

[image]