# Pstricks: Magnetic Field Lines of a Bar Magnet

Tags: pstricks

As the title suggests I am looking for a `pstricks` way to draw the magnetic field lines of a bar magnet.

There are drawings online, for example:
[hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/imgmag/bar.gif](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/imgmag/bar.gif), but I want to use `pstricks`.

[image]

---

Some of the plots online are mathematically not correct, which I consider unfortunate. Wolfram online, however, has some math to do this, [Wolfram Demonstration: Magnetic Field of a Cylindrical Bar Magnet](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MagneticFieldOfACylindricalBarMagnet/).

---

I realize there are some solutions for Tikz, compare [TikZ - Magnetic field lines images method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422153/tikz-magnetic-field-lines-images-method) 
and [TikZ - Magnetic field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315292/tikz-magnetic-field).

I am also aware of the general approach to vector fields, for example [Drawing vector field using PSTricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142010/drawing-vector-field-using-pstricks), but have not been able to do apply this. Also, I would prefer a solution that does not include this process.

There is a `pstricks` package `pst-magneticfield`, but it is for drawing fields of solenoids (basic coils).

### EDIT

I have tried the suggested solution

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-magneticfield}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.75cm}
\begin{pspicture*}(-5,-7)(5,7)
\psBarMagnet[showField](0,0)
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

together with the recent `pst-magneticfield.tex`, but somehow end up with changing linewidths:

[image]

Comment: It’s not every day some asks a question about magnetic fields AND TeX, my two favourite things :-) Note that the magnetic field from an ideal cylindrical magnet is identical to an ideal solenoid of the same dimensions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-magneticfield}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.4}
\begin{pspicture*}(-10,-12)(10,12)
\psmagneticfield[linecolor=black,N=2,R=1,L=1,PasB=0.4,nS=0,nL=7,
  pointsB=1000](-10,-12)(10,12)
\psframe*[linecolor=Green](-1,0)(1,-3)
\psframe*[linecolor=BrickRed](-1,0)(1,3)
\rput(0,-2){\bfseries\textcolor{white}{S}}
\rput(0,2){\bfseries\textcolor{white}{N}}
\end{pspicture*}

%% or with latest pat-magneticfield http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/TeXnik/tex/generic/pst-magneticfield/pst-magneticfield.tex
\psset{unit=0.75cm}
\begin{pspicture*}(-5,-7)(5,7)
\psBarMagnet[showField](0,0)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if there are more than one magnet bar placed relatively closed each other?

Comment: I think the first picture your code produces pretty much the same picture as Raaja's code (see my comments there). I think the second picture rougly shows the field lines for a slightly shorter and thinner magnet and the lines you manually added at the side are probably not correct.

Comment: @Herbert: I have tried your first solution, but agree with Circumscribe that it's "pretty much the same picture as Raaja's code". My problem is with those cusps that seem wrong tbh

Comment: I like your second solution though. Your packages are gold, pure gold

Comment: The linewidths do however change in a strange way. I have tried and failed to get them all the same

Comment: @fborchers: give a hort example and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @Herbert I have added a picture of how it looks on my machine. I use a standard `latex`, `dvips` and `ps2pdf` routine

Comment: I see, will fix it ...

Comment: And uploaded a new version to CTAN

Comment: Thanks, but somehow this did not solve my problem. This might by due to old TeX files on my machine (deb repo) though. I have hacked your code and use multido with `linewidth=0.4\pslinewidth` now, which works for me.

Answer (score 12):

I should preface this answer by saying that I know pretty much nothing about PSTricks and that I had never heard of the `pst-magneticfield` package (which is amazing by the way) before today. I do know some physics though.
Also, I'm assuming a cylindrical magnet counts as a "bar magnet".

The magnetic field generated by a uniformly magnetised cylindrical magnet is identical to that produced by a uniform current along the shell of a cylinder of the same dimensions. 
This can be approximated by a solenoid of the same length and radius with a large number of loops.

The [`pst-magneticfield`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pst-magneticfield) package can draw this if you choose the parameters properly.
My starting point was the code from [Raaja's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470503/156366), which is not quite accurate.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-magneticfield}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5}
\begin{pspicture*}(-20,-16)(20,16)
  \psframe[linecolor=black, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray](-2,-6)(2,6)
  \psmagneticfield[N=128,R=2,L=11.95,
      nL=7,pointsB=4000,
      nS=1,numSpires=13,pointsS=8000,
      linecolor=black,drawSelf=false](-20,-16)(20,16)
  \rput(0,-5.2){\textcolor{white}{S}}
  \rput(0,5.2){\textcolor{white}{N}}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

Producing the following image takes about 110 second on my system if I use XeLaTeX. Running `latex`, `dvips` and then `ps2pdf` (not `pstopdf`) takes about 93 seconds (which is mostly `ps2pdf`s running time).

[image: output]

Note that the field lines coming out the sides don't do so at right angles (which is correct).
I've only drawn one such line for three reasons: (1) the field there is weak, (2) the field inside should be close to uniform and (3) technical reasons.

The technical reason is that the second field line would almost loop back on itself and produce another field line I didn't ask for.
This doesn't happen if `pointsS` is reduced, but it doesn't seem to be possible to choose different values for different coils.
It also appears that nothing is drawn if `nL=0`, even if `nS` is positive. I'm not sure why.

#### Parameters:

- I've set the length `L=11.95` to just a teensy bit less than the length of the magnet and the radius `R=2` to its actual radius.
- I've set the number of coils to `N=128`, which was kind of arbitrary. I'm sure some smaller number would also work.
- `nL=7` is the number of field lines to draw that come out of the ends of the solenoid.
- If you set `nS=0` (number of field lines to draw around each individual coils), only the field lines coming out of the ends of the magnet are shown and if you set `nS=1` things go a little crazy (I would assume, I didn't wait for it).
  I've set `nS=1` and `numSpires=13` to only draw one field line coming out the side for the 13th coil. 
  The number `13` was chosen so that the field lines inside are still roughly uniform, and it was obtained by trial and error.
- The maximum number of points to use for the field lines coming out the ends (`pointsB=4000`) and the same thing for the field lines coming out the sides (`pointsS=8000`) were also obtained by trial end error.

---

## Addendum

I just remembered (thanks in part to a comment by KJO) that the H-field of a uniformly cylindrical (or another shape) magnetised bar is identical to that of two disc-shaped (or other-shaped) monopoles at the ends. The magnetic field is equal to the H-field outside the magnet.

The following is roughly what the magnetic field of two very flat bar magnets should look like in several configurations. 
I've drawn it using the [`pst-electricfield`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pst-electricfield) package. It will likely be qualitatively correct for cylindrical/bar shaped magnets. It does look a little less polished than the other picture.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-electricfield}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5}

\let\oppositeends\empty
\multido{\rA=-2+0.2}{21}{%
  \xdef\oppositeends{\oppositeends[1 \rA\space 6][-1 \rA\space -6][-1 \rA\space 10][1 \rA\space 22]}
}
\begin{pspicture*}(-6,-10)(6,26)
  \psElectricfield[Q={\oppositeends},linecolor=black,N=5,points=1000,radius=0]
  \psframe[linecolor=black, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray=12](-2,-6)(2,6)
  \psframe[linecolor=black, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray=12](-2,10)(2,22)
  \rput(0,-5.2){\textcolor{white}{S}}
  \rput(0,5.2){\textcolor{white}{N}}
  \rput(0,10.8){\textcolor{white}{S}}
  \rput(0,21.2){\textcolor{white}{N}}
\end{pspicture*}

\let\sameends\empty
\multido{\rA=-2+0.2}{21}{%
  \xdef\sameends{\sameends[1 \rA\space 6][-1 \rA\space -6][1 \rA\space 10][-1 \rA\space 22]}
}
\begin{pspicture*}(-6,-10)(6,26)
  \psElectricfield[Q={\sameends},linecolor=black,N=5,points=1000,radius=0]
  \psframe[linecolor=black, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray=12](-2,-6)(2,6)
  \psframe[linecolor=black, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray=12](-2,10)(2,22)
  \rput(0,-5.2){\textcolor{white}{S}}
  \rput(0,5.2){\textcolor{white}{N}}
  \rput(0,10.8){\textcolor{white}{N}}
  \rput(0,21.2){\textcolor{white}{S}}
\end{pspicture*}

\let\sidebyside\empty
\multido{\rA=-2+0.2,\rB=6+0.2}{21}{%
  \xdef\sidebyside{\sidebyside[1 \rA\space 6][-1 \rA\space -6][1 \rB\space 6][-1 \rB\space -6]}
}
\begin{pspicture*}(-6,-10)(14,10)
  \psElectricfield[Q={\sidebyside},linecolor=black,N=5,points=1000,radius=0]
  \psframe[linecolor=black, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray=12](-2,-6)(2,6)
  \psframe[linecolor=black, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray=12](6,-6)(10,6)
  \rput(0,-5.2){\textcolor{white}{S}}
  \rput(0,5.2){\textcolor{white}{N}}
  \rput(8,-5.2){\textcolor{white}{S}}
  \rput(8,5.2){\textcolor{white}{N}}
\end{pspicture*}

\let\reverseside\empty
\multido{\rA=-2+0.2,\rB=6+0.2}{21}{%
  \xdef\reverseside{\reverseside[1 \rA\space 6][-1 \rA\space -6][-1 \rB\space 6][1 \rB\space -6]}
}
\begin{pspicture*}(-6,-10)(14,10)
  \psElectricfield[Q={\reverseside},linecolor=black,N=5,points=1000,radius=0]
  \psframe[linecolor=black, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray=12](-2,-6)(2,6)
  \psframe[linecolor=black, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray=12](6,-6)(10,6)
  \rput(0,-5.2){\textcolor{white}{S}}
  \rput(0,5.2){\textcolor{white}{N}}
  \rput(8,-5.2){\textcolor{white}{N}}
  \rput(8,5.2){\textcolor{white}{S}}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

(Drawing all four of these took about 220 second with `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf` by the way.)

[image: output]

I've drawn the magnets over the field lines because the lines inside the magnet are field lines for the H-field rather than for the B-field.
For completeness, here is a version where I'm not covering them up:

[image: With H-field]

Comment: It's really beautiful, I admire it!

Answer (score 7):

As a first try, you can tweak the `<options>` of `pst-magneticfield` as in

```
%&pdflatex
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-magneticfield}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks-add, auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}

 \psset{unit=0.5}
 \begin{pspicture*}(-10,-12)(10,12)
 \psframe[linecolor=black, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray](-2,-3)(2,3)
 \psmagneticfield[linecolor=black,N=2,R=2,L=1,PasB=0.4,nS=0,nL=7,pointsB
=1000](-10,-12)(10,12)
 \rput(0,-2.6){\textcolor{white}{S}}
 \rput(0,2.6){\textcolor{white}{N}}
 \end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

to achieve something closer to your requirement as in

[image]

However, this is not the exact output you would desire. Plese note that I still am figuring out how to remove the red-lines that is appearing over the magnet. Also, dont forgot to escape the shell, if you are compiling with `pdflatex` which is necessary due to the usage of `auto-pst-pdf`.
** Update 1** By making drawSelf = false, you can remove the unwanted coils atop your magnets.

```
\psmagneticfield[linecolor=black,N=2,R=2,L=1,PasB=0.4,nS=0,nL=7,pointsB=1000, drawSelf = false]
```

This gives:

[image]

**Addendum 1:**

Apparently scripting this from scratch yields much more better results and makes our life easier ;). However, I am not sure of the technical accuracy! So, what do we need: A few *ellipses, a box, a straight line and finally a few texts*.

**Note:** This script can be optimised much better than it is currently presented.

```
%&pdflatex
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]
\documentclass[a4paper, pdf, x11names]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks-add, auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
    \psset{unit = 6mm}
    \begin{pspicture}(-5,-4)(2,4)
    % magnet
    \psframe[linecolor=black, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray](-3,-2.5)(0,2.5)
    %right side
    \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red]{->}(0.4,0)(1,2){0}{360}
    \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red]{->}(0.4,0)(1.2,2.7){0}{360}
        \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red]{->}(0.4,0)(1.4,3.4){0}{360}
        %closing the gaps
            \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red](0.4,0)(1,2){350}{10}
        \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red](0.4,0)(1.2,2.7){350}{10}
        \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red](0.4,0)(1.4,3.4){350}{10}
                %left side and mirror
                \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red]{<-}(-3.4,0)(1,2){-180}{0}
                \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red]{<-}(-3.4,0)(1.2,2.7){-180}{0}
                \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red]{<-}(-3.4,0)(1.4,3.4){-180}{0}
                \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red](-3.4,0)(1,2){0}{190}
                \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red](-3.4,0)(1.2,2.7){0}{190}
                \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red](-3.4,0)(1.4,3.4){0}{190}
                %interesting stuff
                \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red]{-<}(-3.4,0)(1.6,4.1){-90}{80}
                \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red](-3.4,0)(1.6,4.1){70}{90}
                \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red]{>-}(0.4,0)(1.6,4.1){100}{-90}
                \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red](0.4,0)(1.6,4.1){90}{110}
                % allied extras
                \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red]{-<}(-3.4,0)(1.8,4.8){-90}{80}
                \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red](-3.4,0)(1.8,4.8){70}{90}
                \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red]{>-}(0.4,0)(1.8,4.8){100}{-90}
                \psellipticarc[rot=0, linecolor = red](0.4,0)(1.8,4.8){90}{110}
                %the straight strip
                \psline[linecolor=red]{>-}(-1.5,4)(-1.5,-4)
                \psline[linecolor=red](-1.5,4)(-1.5,3.9)
                %which direction is my magnetic field going huh?
                \rput(-1.5,-2.1){N}
                \rput(-1.5,2.1){S}
                % now you know
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives,

[image]

**Addendum 2:** Based on `@GodMustBeCrazy`'s comment on `What if there is more than one magnet`, we can achieve close to desired results by abusing the `pst-electricfield` package as in

```
%&pdflatex
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]
\documentclass[a4paper, pdf, x11names]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-electricfield}
\usepackage{pstricks-add, auto-pst-pdf}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308036/how-to-draw-a-circle-with-black-border-with-pstricks
\begin{document}
    \psset{unit = 6mm}
    \begin{pspicture*}(-6,-6)(6,6)
\psframe*[linecolor=white!50](-6,-6)(6,6)
\psElectricfield[Q={[-1 -2 2][1 2 2][-1 2 -2][1 -2 -2]},linecolor=red, radius=0.1]
% fitting the magnets
\psframe[linecolor=black, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray](-2.3,-2.5)(-1.7,-1.5)
\psframe[linecolor=black, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray](-2.3,2.5)(-1.7,1.5)
\psframe[linecolor=black, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray](2.3,-2.5)(1.7,-1.5)
\psframe[linecolor=black, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray](2.3,2.5)(1.7,1.5)
% drawing N-S
 \rput(-2,-2.3){\textcolor{white}{\tiny S}}
\rput(-2,-1.7){\textcolor{white}{\tiny N}}
 \rput(-2,2.3){\textcolor{white}{\tiny N}}
\rput(-2,1.7){\textcolor{white}{\tiny S}}
 \rput(2,-2.3){\textcolor{white}{\tiny N}}
\rput(2,-1.7){\textcolor{white}{\tiny S}}
 \rput(2,2.3){\textcolor{white}{\tiny S}}
\rput(2,1.7){\textcolor{white}{\tiny N}}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

This is just a try for fun, I am really not sure about the technical accuracy of the results (been a little rusty in electromagnetics, been a long since I looked into them). Thanks to `@Herbert` for a nice answer that he made in the past ;)

Comment: Good idea. You can put the bar magnet _ over_ the field lines. See first example in my answer.

Comment: @Herbert I specifically did not do that because in OP's example, the field lines were visible atop the magnet :D

Comment: You can use `drawSelf=false` to get rid of the red coils.

Comment: @Herbert I tried that one with `lualatex` threw some errors, but after I reach home, I will check and update the answer ;) thanks for info!

Comment: I don't think these pictures are correct. You're approximating a bar magnet by just two coils somewhere near its center instead of a coil with an infinite number of loops along its entire length. Inside, the field lines inside should be mostly parallel along the entire length and the few coming out the side should bend backwards. They're definitely not ellipses (and they do not come close together far away from the magnet).

Comment: @Circumscribe I really dont know the technical accuracy which, I would whole heartedly agree :). However, this is just "an approach" which,  someone with the background can play with.

Comment: @Raaja: Fair enough. I just wanted to point this out since mathematical/physical accuracy was stressed in the question.

Comment: @Circumscribe I completely agree :), that's why after the **addendum 2**, I posted a remark explicitly stating that this is for fun :D

Comment: It'll probably be mostly accurate if you set `L` to the actual length (`L=6` in this case) and `N` to some large number (let's say `N=65`). I think the package doesn't draw the lines coming out the sides by design (though there shouldn't be many of them since the field there is weak), but you can draw two by adding e.g. `nS=1,numSpires=8 33` (doesn't look good).

Comment: @Circumscribe I will try your suggestions, however I am little bit vary about the expected outcome per se.

Comment: @Raaja: Do you mind if I post that as an answer?

Comment: @Circumscribe you can post that as an answer, I don't mind at all :)

Comment: Raaja I too can be forgetting my old lab teachers experiments with iron filings however I think the last example is based on 2 magnets rather than 4 the flow (flux) is traditionally N to S thus either a top bar S to N above a bottom bar N to S alternatively left hand bar S down to N with RH bar from N down to S

Comment: @KJO: The last image shows (a) the electric field lines for four electrically charged particles, (b) the magnetic field lines for four magnetic monopoles (which probably don't exist) or (c) the magnetic field lines of two infinitely thin permanent magnets with endpoints at these four spots.

Comment: @Circumscribe If I recollect (probably badly without checking) my reading of elctro package was the convergence of two dipole antenna (e.g. similar to two double ended objects)

Comment: @KJO I shall look into it and correct them.

Comment: @Circumscribe saw it, seems to match some of my expectation though without some nails and a couple of magnets I cant tell how accurate the fields follow reality :-)

Comment: This last picture cannot be correct as the magnetic field lines cannot cross. If the field is zero in the center (by symmetry) it would be necessary to omit those lines.

Comment: @fborchers As I have stated in my answer, the last part is just for fun. It is already mentioned that it is technically inaccurate :)